# Error: Cannot call member function without object

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem when compiling this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Class1
{   
    public:
        string m_Ime;
        Class1(const string ime);
};

Class1::Class1(string const ime):
    m_Ime(ime)
{}

class Class2
{
    public:
        vector <Class1> m_Class1;
        Class2(int mesta);
        void RollCall();
        void Add(const Class1& aClass1);
};

Class2::Class2(int mesta)
{
    m_Class1.reserve(mesta);
}

void Class2::RollCall()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < m_Class1.size(); x++){
        cout << m_Class1[x].m_Ime << endl;
    }
    
}

void Class2::Add(const Class1& aClass1)
{
    m_Class1.push_back(aClass1);
}

int main(){
    Class2 skupina (3);
    
    Class2::Add(Class1 ("Prvi"));
    Class2::Add(Class1 ("Drugi"));
    Class2::Add(Class1 ("Tretji"));
    
    skupina.RollCall();
    
    return 0;
}
```

It's nothing more than me trying to learn the basics of aggregation. However when trying to compile the code, it gives me the following errors:

> In function 'int main()':
>
> 46 29 [Error] cannot call member function 'void Class2::Add(const Class1&)' without object
>
> 47 30 [Error] cannot call member function 'void Class2::Add(const Class1&)' without object
>
> 48 31 [Error] cannot call member function 'void Class2::Add(const Class1&)' without object

Even if I instantiate 3 objects of the type `Class1` and then call the `Add` function with them as arguments, the same error persists.

Answer (score 3):

Member functions operate on an instance. But to specify *which instance* the member function will operate on, you need to call the function *on that instance*.

To do that, instead of the class name, use an expression that evaluates to that instance (for example, the automatic variable you have declared):

```
skupina.Add(...);
```

Now the member function will know which instance to operate on.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
skupina.Add(Class1 ("Prvi"));
skupina.Add(Class1 ("Drugi"));
skupina.Add(Class1 ("Tretji"));
```

instead of:

```
Class2::Add(Class1 ("Prvi"));
Class2::Add(Class1 ("Drugi"));
Class2::Add(Class1 ("Tretji"));
```

Consider the following:

```
Class2 skupina1 (3);
Class2 skupina2 (3);

Class2::Add(Class1 ("Prvi"));
```

How the compiler could know on which object (`skupina1` or `skupina2`) the `Add` method should be called?

You need to say explicitly into which object you want to `Add` something: `skupina1.Add(Class1("Prvi"));` or `skupina2.Add(Cass1("Prvi"));`.

Comment: This should complement the answer: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/